# Converting a URL with a whole JSON object into SEO friendly URL

Tags: json, angularjs, url, nginx, seo

One of our developers has decided to pass a whole JSON object in the URL because the state of the page needs to be rebuilt when shared on social media or elsewhere. Here is an example of one such URL:

```
<mydomain.com>/<my-route>/{"AspectValues":{"camera":3,"battery":3,"display":3,"performance":3},"PriceMinValue":5000,"PriceMaxValue":90000,"SelectedBrandFilters":[],"SelectedOsFilters":[],"SpecificationWeight":3,"SentimentWeight":3,"ExcludedBrandList":[],"SelectedScreenFilter":["3-4","4-4.5","4.5-5","5-5.5","5.5-6","6-above"],"TimeSort":null,"PriceSort":null,"ScoreSort":null,"allPhones":false,"category":"Smartphones"}
```

Firstly, this URL does not seem SEO-friendly and Secondly, it does not look good. We are using nginx as our webserver and AngularJS as a JS Framework.

I want to know what are the options I could explore to resolve this situation without breaking much in the current JS implementation to re-construct the page.

Using nginx to rewrite seems like one option but the route mapping to create SEO-friendly URLs and still obtain all the information in the JSON URL seems pretty tricky. Any other ideas will really be helpful.

Thanks a lot, people. :)

Comment: why can't it be done with search params? Only include params that aren't defaults also

Comment: Almost all the attributes in the JSON are changeable. This is because they are either user selected attributes before landing on this page or in-page filters. Changing them will lead to a certain state and we would like to be able to recreate the state in a browser on a different machine.

Comment: but using search params would at least look cleaner than all that raw json. And if certain variables aren't changed you don't need to whole state in url ...such as unused filters

Comment: It's not a nginx's job. Change your application to use query params or live with it.

Comment: My problem is not actually a comparison between query params or json object. Using query params is not SEO friendly as well. SEO-friendly URLs are generally static and query params are also dynamic. I want to be able to use URLs like "<mydomain.com>/best-camera-phones". How do we accomplish this?